# Changing the first letters of words in a string to uppercase in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase, words

Can we capitalize the first letters of words in a string to Uppercase and return the string without using slice(1) in javascript? If possible please help me find this out?

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str=str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+str[i].slice(1);
  }
  str=str.join(" ");
  return str;
}
titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt");
```

Comment: `substring(1)` but what is the concern with `slice(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  });
}

console.log(titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt"));
```